# bluetoothctl "Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable" while connect to Sony DPT-RP1 digital paper

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to Sony DPT-RP1 digital paper from Ubuntu 20.04. From the bluetoothctl interface, pairing is successful however I just can't connect to the device. Sorry I'm completely noob in Linux and I'm trying my best to be informative.

`bluetoothctl connect A8:1D:16:07:DA:B4` gives:

```
[bluetooth]# connect A8:1D:16:07:DA:B4
Attempting to connect to A8:1D:16:07:DA:B4
[CHG] Device A8:1D:16:07:DA:B4 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device A8:1D:16:07:DA:B4 ServicesResolved: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
```

And after seconds:

```
[CHG] Device A8:1D:16:07:DA:B4 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device A8:1D:16:07:DA:B4 Connected: no
```

`bluetoothctl paired-devices` gives:

```
Device A8:1D:16:07:DA:B4 DPT-RP1_6305093
```

`bluetoothctl info A8:1D:16:07:DA:B4` gives:

```
Device A8:1D:16:07:DA:B4 (public)  
    Name: DPT-RP1_6305093  
    Alias: DPT-RP1_6305093  
    Class: 0x0002020c  
    Icon: phone
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: NAP                       (00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v054Cp0BE5d0100
```

I tried to Google search `Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable` but all results seem to be related to Rasberry Pi or PulseAudio Sound device which is not quite relevant.

I also tried the GUI bluetooth settings and the "connection" button is completely unclickable:

[image: as seen here].

And I tried to restart both my computer and Digital Paper, or re-pair after removing all pairing info but didn't work. And completely reset the Digital Paper didn't help either.

Could anyone tell me what could be wrong here? Deeply appreciate it.
Also, the reason I stick to a bluetooth connection is that I would need it to manage files later through the [dpt-rp1-py](https://github.com/janten/dpt-rp1-py) package. Also, wired connection is not supported on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (see https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bluetooth-basics/all) you only need to use 'connect' only if the device is not paired.
If it is paired all you should have to do is turn your device (sony) on and off, and when it turns on again it should connect to bluetooth.
You use connect if you do't want to use pairing.